# VBA Dynamically use the results in Cell in place of hard scripted name

Tags: excel, vba

I have names that are obtained in Cell B13 via this formula
=MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,FIND("]", CELL("filename",$A$1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1)

And In Cell F13 by this formula =LEFT($B$13,6)&"_Loader"&RIGHT($B$13,5)
They yield the names 
MDS_V3.1.0_Prod_.xlsb & MDS_V3_Loader.xlsb  respectively but those names will change as I release additional versions of the sheet and I don't want to go back through all my VBA to manually insert the differences. So what I am wanting is to replace the names Hard Coded in the script with the results of thos cells but I am having trouble with assigning the results of those to variables that will work.  Can somebody assist?

```
Sub GetData()
'
' GetData Macro
' Get Data From MDS Loader
'

'
    Windows("MDS_V3_Loader.xlsb").Activate
    Range("C2:D2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("MDS_V3.1.0_Prod_.xlsb").Activate
    Range("C2:D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Where is your problem exactly?

Comment: So the macro is going to sit in one of these files? Or in something separate?

Comment: defining the variable that will replace the "MDS_V3_Loader.xlsb" that is actually derived from the formulas in the two cells F13 and B13 The file names will change so hard coding the names in the activate statements wont work  I need a variable like .. dim loader as workbook and dim target as workbook and then have those variables in place of the MDS_V3_Loader.xlsb  and the  MDS_V3.1.0_Prod_.xlsb but everything I have tried I cant seem to make work in  the activate statements (I have a bunch as it copies) just showing the top two

Comment: When I set a new version I want to ensure they are using the proper loader with the same amount of fields on the target and the source workbooks that's why I want it to ONLY work between the names shown in cells B13 and F13 the easiest net is how do I assign a variable that will get it's assignment name from the result of a formula in a cell that will work in the Windows("Variable").Activate  statement

Comment: The Macro is in the MDS_V3.1.0_Prod_.xlsb workbook. The loader has no code it is just the source of the copy that way they can't mess up the format or validation I have in my main workbook

Comment: Why arent you linking to the cells where you have the workbooknames in? Like `C2` and `D2`

Comment: I don't want to link two workbooks together I am trying to absolutely protect the integrity of the master for version control and make it impossible for someone to rename either and expect them to work. So suffice it to say I want a foolproof way to control input. 30 copies or more will be sent out to various users. If someone knows how to assign a variable to the activate statement shown please speak up, but I am not looking for an alternative way to make my sheet just a way to make what I have designed work.

Comment: Its really a simple question how would I define a variable that would place the workbook name in this statement that will actually work    Windows("MDS_V3_Loader.xlsb").Activate  Becomes Windows("Variable").Activate

Comment: Then second the actual name of the workbook is derived from a formula in cell F13. The code will be in the same worksheet that the formula is in.   So the Dim and Set statements are what I am looking for that will make that variable work in THAT specific statement or is that impossible with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself  The answer is

```
   Dim Main as String
   Dim Loader as String
   Main = Range ("B13").Value
   Loader = Range ("F13).Value
   Windows(Loader).Activate
   Range("C2:D2").Select 
   ' etcetera
```

The big thing is Correct Dim statements and the Variable without the quotes  I am a novice at this

Comment: Kind of bewildered why nobody else spoke up